# 'this' returns array instead of a string. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I'am reading book "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja, Second Edition" And it has this code:

```
function forEach(list,callback) { 
   for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
      callback.call(list[n],n); 
   }
}

var weapons = ['shuriken','katana','nunchucks']; 
forEach(weapons, function(index){ 
    assert(this == weapons[index], 
    "Got the expected value of " + weapons[index]); 
});
```

Which seems to be okay according to book. When "assert" happens 'this' returned as a string.
But when I run the code myself 'this' returned as an array of characters.

`0: "a"
1: "x"
2: "e"
length: 3`

This is my copy of the code with a small change  `this.toString()` and it works as in the book (I hope...)

```
function forEach(list, callback) {
    for (let n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
        callback.call(list[n], n);
    }
}
let weapons = [
    'axe',
    'sword',
    'mace'
];
forEach(weapons, function (index) {
    console.assert(this.toString() === weapons[index], `Got the expected value of ${weapons[index]}`)
})
```

What have I missed or did not understand? Why the same code gives different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very interesting piece of code and I will be looking out for that book. Before anything, how is the **assert** method implemented? I have done a small code block assuming how the **assert** method was implemented.

The important piece of the code in the `forEach` function is the `callback.call` method. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)
>   thisArg
>   Optional. The value of this provided for the call to a function. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.

Essentially, the `this` becomes the value from `list`, in this case, each word. Also you mentioned

> run the code myself 'this' returned as an array of characters

It's a string, which is an array of characters. In a string you can do `nameOfStringVar[index]` and you will get the position of that character.

```js
console.log("hello"[1]);
```

It is not an array but a String instance. Also, you are forcing a type comparison with `===`, as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

> triple equals (===) will do the same comparison (including the special handling for NaN, -0, and +0) but without type conversion, by simply always returning false if the types differ;

But one would think if `this` is supposed to be **list[n]** how is that not `===` that same `list[n]`?

I assume behind curtains JS is creating a new object based on the value passed, and that's why '===' returns false. I am searching this as I type, if I find anything specific I will edit this answer.

I thought of the following, using [mauke's piece of code](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mauke/2010/08/javascript-adding-a-unique-id-to-every-object.html) I add an id to every object created. You'll see then that the `this` has a different `id` from the `weapons[index]`.

```js
var enchant = (function () {
    var k = 'id';
    var uniq = 0;

    return function enchant(o) {
        var t = uniq++;
        o[k] = function () {
            return this === o ? t : enchant(this, k);
        };
        return t;
    };
}());

enchant(Object.prototype);

function forEach(list,callback) { 
   for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
      callback.call(list[n],n); 
      //list[n] is the new this, essentially the word
   }
}

function assert(expression, message){
 if(expression)
     console.log(message);
 else
     console.log("Not equal");
}

var weapons = ['shuriken','katana','nunchucks']; 
forEach(weapons, function(index){ 
    console.log("this id is --> " + this.id());
    console.log("weapoins[index] id is --> " + weapons[index].id());
    assert(this == weapons[index],
    "Got the expected value of " + weapons[index]); 
});
```

```js
function forEach(list,callback) { 
   for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
      callback.call(list[n],n); 
      //list[n] is the new this, essentially the word
   }
}

function assert(expression, message){
 if(expression)
     console.log(message);
 else
     console.log("Not equal");
}

var weapons = ['shuriken','katana','nunchucks']; 
forEach(weapons, function(index){ 
    assert(this == weapons[index],
    "Got the expected value of " + weapons[index]); 
});
```

Comment: Yes, your code works perfectly now. Turned out problem was in `console.assert`. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/assert). Turns out it prints only if statement is `false`. Also, helped me to understand that this actually returned instance of a `String`, thanks `Yury Tarabanko`.

Comment: Thanks, this explains what happens under the hood. Actually, more then I have expected.

Comment: Awesome, I also learned as well, it's the beauty of this site, hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

> "But when I run the code myself 'this' returned as an array of characters."

It is not an array but a `String` instance.

When using `Function.prototype.call` with primitive value `thisArgument` is auto-boxed (see [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis))

> 6.b.i Let thisValue be ToObject(thisArgument).

If you use strict comparison (`===`) types are not coerrced so `new String('a') === 'a'` yields false.

```js
function forEach(list, callback) {
  for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
    callback.call(list[n], n);
  }
}
var weapons = ['shuriken', 'katana', 'nunchucks'];
forEach(weapons, function(index) {
  console.log(typeof this, this instanceof String) //object true
  console.assert(this === weapons[index],
    "Got the expected value of " + weapons[index]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't work because index is not defined. You can pass index as parameter only if you use [native JS method for array](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (Array.forEach()). In your case 'this' will refer to global object 'Window', so if you stringify it you'll get "[object Window]"

Comment: Well, this is simply not true. `index` is defined. The value of `this` is a string.